# Python error fetch email from Gmail

Tags: python

i have python script like this to get email from my gmail. In some email i can get the csv file, but there are 1 email that got an error.

This is my script:

```
import poplib
import email
import os

detach_dir = '.' # directory where to save attachments (default: current)

class GmailTest(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.savedir="/tmp"

def test_save_attach(self):
    self.connection = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com', 995)
    self.connection.set_debuglevel(1)
    self.connection.user("email.google")
    self.connection.pass_("Password")

    emails, total_bytes = self.connection.stat()
    print("{0} emails in the inbox, {1} bytes total".format(emails, total_bytes))
    # return in format: (response, ['mesg_num octets', ...], octets)
    msg_list = self.connection.list()
    print(msg_list)

    # messages processing
    for i in range(emails):

        # return in format: (response, ['line', ...], octets)
        response = self.connection.retr(i+1)
        raw_message = response[1]

        str_message = email.message_from_string('\n'.join(raw_message))

        # save attach
        for part in str_message.walk():
            print(part.get_content_type())

            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                print("no content dispo")
                continue

            filename = part.get_filename()
    counter  = 1

     # if there is no filename, we create one with a counter to avoid duplicates
    if not filename:
        filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, 'bin')
        counter += 1

    att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

    #Check if its already there
    if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
        # finally write the stuff
        fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        fp.close()
          #  if not(filename): filename = "test.txt"
          #  print(filename)

           # fp = open(os.path.join(self.savedir, filename), 'wb')
           # fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=1))
           # fp.close

    #I  exit here instead of pop3lib quit to make sure the message doesn't get removed in gmail
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)

d=GmailTest()
d.test_save_attach()
```

there are error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getmail.py", line 71, in <module>
d.test_save_attach()
File "getmail.py", line 47, in test_save_attach
if not filename:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment
```

please help, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a variable scope issue.

In line 22 add `filename = None`.

The reason you're getting this error is because in line 47 the variable `filename` has not been declared. You declare it in line 43 inside the `for` loop and when the loop exits it's not there.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

Comment: Alkar, Yes, its working now. but in some emails even i dont add the filename=None it still retrieving the attachment.any idea?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a case where there the filename variable is not being initialised. You need to create a default initialisation line above this line of code:

```
for i in range(emails):
```

Eg:

```
filename = None
```